# Storing User-Entered Table Data In Browser

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, local-storage

Basically, I have a page on an MVC site that allows the user to add rows to a table and modify the data on each row (via dropdowns and textboxes). One of the requirements is that if the user refreshes the page, the data is somehow saved and reloaded into the table.

Not only is it vital to retain the data on the client-side but refreshing the page will trigger a GET and thus call the Index action of the page. The Index action (at the moment) assumes that the page is loading for the first time and thus it doesn't care about any existing table data. However, the this page isn't a page that the user can currently access on its own. The user arrives on this page after filling out data on a previous page. That data (from said previous page) is stored in TempData and passed over to the VM for this page when the Index action is triggered. The server-side problem is that the TempData won't exist when the user refreshes the page.

The solution that I thought of was this.

Provide a JavaScript function that triggers via `$(window).bind('pageunload', ...);`. This function would serialize the table as a JSON object and store it in the local storage with a key. When the page loads, JavaScript will check to see if that key exists in local storage. If so, it will load the table, which should still include all data that it needs to POST back to the server and bind to the Action (with its View Model) successfully.

There are two question that come from this proposed solution:

1. Is this a good solution. If not, what would be best.
2. If #1 is 'yes', what shall I do on the server-side to let the Index action know that the page is being reloaded and so it shouldn't page any attention to the TempData (perhaps just check if TempData is null and return an empty VM if so???)

Thanks in advance for your answers.